# Removing blank spaces from the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column as name which is having a results like.

```
name
ABC
XYZ
   ader
fer
```

I want to remove the blank space before ader and it should print in the output like
ader.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Look into using `trim` functions.  Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your database you can use `trim()`, `ltrim()`/`rtrim()`, or `replace()`:

```
select replace(name, ' ', '')
select trim(name, ' ')
select ltrim(rtrim(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` functions to remove trailing and leading spaces.

```
SELECT
    RTRIM(LTRIM(name)) AS name
FROM yourTable
```